# Why is the output 0 2 all the time when it should be garbage?

Tags: c, unions

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    union a
    {
        int i;
        char ch[2];
    };  
    union a z = {512};
    printf("%d %d",z.ch[0],z.ch[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: 0 2
Why is the output 0 2, when it should be some garbage value?

Comment: "0 2" is just as garbage as anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you expect the compiler to generate garbage for you, when you have just told it to initialize to `i` to `512`. The least two significant bytes of 512 are `0` and `2`.

Implementation-specific behavior is not the same as garbage.

Comment: I have initialized i to 512, then how are the values of z.ch[0] and z.ch[1] becoming 0 and 2? According to me it should be garbage values since we are just initializing i and not ch[]. 
If I am wrong please explain what actually happens? I have just learned about unions.

Comment: @Sagar, The members of a `union` share the same memory address. When you initialize `i` and read `ch`, you are basically interpreting the 4 bytes you just wrote into `i` as individual bytes using `ch`.